# VBA Pivot Table One Cell Reference Different Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this current code to update a pivot table filter based on a cell value (E1) within the same sheet. What i would like to do is to update a filter based on a cell in a sheet named summary. If I set the filed in the current filed equal to the cell in the summary I need to press f2 and enter otherwise it won't work. I'm sure a little bit of tweaking and my code could work for it.

Any tips?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Set Target = Range("E1")
If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("Tech Pivot Table").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
With Me.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    .PivotCache.Refresh
    .PivotFields("Name").CurrentPage = Target.Value
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True





     End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, using `On Error Resume Next` (unless for a **_very_** specific purpose that you know will occasionally fail but be handled accordingly) is not the best practice, as it hides errors that could otherwise be important to see, making it very hard to debug code

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're changing the value the Target variable up front when you should be checking to see if Target = "E1".  Try the code below and let me know if it works.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = Range("E1") Then
        If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("Tech Pivot Table").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
        With Me.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
            .PivotCache.Refresh
            .PivotFields("Name").CurrentPage = Target.Value
        End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Phillip, this code works in the same fashion as my previous one. The problem is that I'm trying to link the cell E1 to a different sheet. The ideal situation is to update the name in summary, and then it would automatically update the pivot table filter in the tech pivot table sheet

Comment: but when I let E1=summary!E1 the only way to get the pivot to update is by pressing F2 and Enter. So I'd like to avoid that.